# XAMPP access over a LAN with Win XP

Tags: testing, windows-xp, xampp, remote-access, lan

I have a development computer and a testing (http://testing/) server set up on my home LAN.  I need to be able to set up the same file directory structure on the testing computer as is on my hosted account.  I am using the /testing/ computer to stage development prior to making it public.

I am using Dreamweaver 8 as my dev platform and I am having a hard time reconciling the local vs. testing vs. remote server environments to allow for the same addressing of images, files, etc. on both the testing and remote (hosted) machines.  If I use the "../dir/sub-dir/filename.php" it works only on the testing server (LAN), whereas when I use the "/dir/sub-dir/filename.php" it only works on the remote (hosted) machine.

I need to configure XAMPP to allow the testing machine to utilize the same addressing structure as the remote (hosted) machine does.

Any ideas?  (Please don't tell me to dump Dreamweaver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matteo, Dreamweaver is fine.

Just go into the Apache config in your XAMPP install and set DOCROOT to the root of your test application and restart Apache.

Comment: That solved it.  I was even able to set it up as http://domain.test.  Thanks for the assist!